# Get type of variable at run-time without having it assigned to an instance of an object and without mirrors

Tags: dart

Is it possible to get the type of a variable in Dart at run-time, without having it assigned to an instance of an object and without using mirrors?

I know I can do this without mirrors (which is great!):

```dart
Foo foo;
foo = new Foo();
var fooType = foo.runTimeType; // This will give me a type of "Foo"
```

But I want to know the type of the variable before it is assigned to an object:

```dart
Foo foo;
var fooType = foo.runTimeType; // This will not give me a type of "Foo"
```

I am guessing it is not possible since the typing info is lost in run-time but would like to have it confirmed.

(My actual scenario is that I am doing dependency injection into a Polymer Element using Custom Events. I would like to put as much of this code as possible in an element base-class and have as little code as possible in each derived element class. One thing that I need to do this is to know the type of variables that are to be injected).

Comment: If foo would be initialized with `foo = new Bar();` (where `Bar extends Foo`) you wouldn't get `Foo` with the first variant neither.